# keeping the values of forms in c#

Tags: c#

I have two forms, form1 and form2. In form1, I have one label and two buttons. when I click on the button1, the result is shown in the label. Now, I click the second button and the form2 is loaded. in form2, I have one button and with clicking on it, form2 is closed and form1 is loaded. My question is here when form1 is loaded, the result does not exist in the label.
how to keep the result in a special form when I go to another form and come back.

The following code is for Form1 and second button

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 s = new Form2();
        s.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

The following code is for Form2 and  button1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 s = new Form1();
        s.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

My problem was solved by the following code.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   Form2 s = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().LastOrDefault();
        if (null == s)
        {
            s = new Form2();
            s.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            s.Activate();
            s.Visible = true;
        }
        this.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, so we can tell you what you are doing wrong. The given answer, should work since you are only hiding/showing the form and never destroy and re-create it. - You are probably re-creating the form at some place and thats why its as if you never entered a value, but without code we cannot tell you where your problem is and have to guess.

Comment: What you want to do can be accomplished using only forms, but I would not do it that way. I would follow a design pattern like MVP, which works quite well with WinForms. That way, the data does not reside in the view and can be populated in new views if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FormsTest{

        Form1 form1;
        Form2 form2;

        public FormsTest(){
            form1 = new Form1();
            form2 = new Form2();
        }

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            form1.Show();
            form2.Hide();
     }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            form2.Show();
            form1.Hide();
    }

}
```

This is roughly what you should be looking for. This solution saves 2 forms variables in a space that both buttons can access them and where their references are not lost.

Your current solution is creating forms inside click handler functions then they are lost at the end of the function, only to have a new one created and lost again the next time you click a button.

Comment: Yes, how to do it?

Comment: You didn't specify exactly what you are using but I would suspect you have access to something akin to a "Visibility" property or literal Hide/Show functions.

Comment: Windows forms for example have a .Visible property.

Comment: I tried it but when coming back to the main form(form1), all information does not exist

Comment: I wrote it, Please see it

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect changes in your question.

Comment: Form2 s = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().LastOrDefault();
            if (null == s)
            {
                s = new Form2();
                s.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                s.Activate();
                s.Visible = true;
            }
            this.Visible = false;

Comment: My problem was solved by other code that I wrote above.